# How to change a VM from split across multiple .vmdk files to a single one or two?

Tags: virtualization, virtual-machines, vmware-player

I have a VM with 3 partitions.  One main one, one for swap space, one for storage.  However, there are dozens of .vmdk files.  Some of those .vmdk files are very large (over 1 GB), but the majority are just over 1 MB.

I want to change this, so that there are only a few .vmdk files.  Ideally, I would like one .vmdk file for the main OS + swap space, and one for storage.  Is this possible?  How would I do it?

Comment: Are they snapshots? Are they all current and in use? I don't know how it got into that state, but how about using VMWare Converter to clone it into a new virtual machine, and choose to make fewer disk files during the clone process? (Use thick provisioned disks, and don't check "make a file per partition" and you will get one vmdk with all partitions in it, at least).

Comment: They're in this state because coffee probably selected the 2GB split files option when creating the virtual disk.

Comment: Furthermore, the 2GB split file option was to address/work with the 2GB FAT-16 partition size limitation (as well as other older file systems).

Answer (score 9):

The best way to join split vmdk's is via the vmware-vdiskmanager utility. For example,

```
vmware-vdiskmanager.exe -r first-of-many.vmdk -t 0 Merged.vmdk
```

`-r` specifies the target disk, `-t` specifies the kind of disk that will be created.

In this case, `0` creates a grow-able disk in a single file. This command should leave the original split vmdk's in place, so that you can verify everything is functioning properly with the newly created disk.

See http://www.vmware.com/pdf/VirtualDiskManager.pdf for documentation.

The vmdk's themselves do not represent individual partitions. If you're looking to have a separate vmdk for the OS swap space and storage, you need to create them on separate virtual disks. In other words, swap space has a 1GB virtual hard drive to itself.

Comment: Yep, and VMware's Disk Manager is *not* a separate install. On Windows you can find it at the installation directory of VMware i.e. `C:\Program Files\VMware\VMware Workstation`. Just thought I'd mention that.

Comment: And on OSX `/Applications/VMware Fusion.app/Contents/Library/vmware-vdiskmanager`

Comment: Since I can't comment, adding this to answer. If you've installed vmware workstation on a linux distro, you can find vmware-vdiskmanager at /usr/bin/vmware-vdiskmanager.